# MRO (Method Resolution Order) in Python for this code

Tags: python, class, inheritance, method-resolution-order

I got this code:

```
class A:
    def gg(self):
        print ('Class A')
        
class B(A):
    def gg(self):
        print('First Class B')
        super().gg()
        print('Class B')
        
class C(A):
    def gg(self):
        print('First Class C')
        super().gg()
        print('Class C')
        
class D (B,C):
        
    def gg(self):
        print('First Class D')
        super().gg()
        print('Class D')

        
good = D()

good.gg()
```

The print expected in my opinion should be:

1. "First Class D" as is the first element in the function
2. "First Class B" as it goes through super and is the first element of the firt inherit class
3. "Class A" as it goes through the second element (a super) of the first inherit class and this is the first element of the reinherit class
4. "Class B" as it goes through the third element of the first inherit class
5. "First Class C" as it goes though the first element of the second inherit class
6. "Class A" as it goes through the second element (a super) of the second inherit class and this is the first element of the reinherit class
7. "Class C" as it goes though the third element of the second inherit class
8. "Class D" as it goes to the las element of the class

Instead, the print is this one:

```
First Class D
First Class B
First Class C
Class A
Class C
Class B
Class D
```

I do not understand any of this prints. Overall, what I do not understand is how it can go from "First Class B" to "First Class C" without passing through the prints "Class A" and "Class B". But what is even more difficult to understand is how can it goes from the prints "Class A" to "Class C" if I am inherting first the class B as we saw that the print 'First Class B" goes before "First Class C" and is not printing 'Class B' before 'Class C'. Also it will be nice if you explain why my expectations are wrong step by step

Comment: Python will tell you the MRO - `D.mro()` -> `[<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]`. Beyond that I'm not sure why you expected different results - when you call `super().gg()` the caller then waits for the callee to finish before reaching its second print.

Comment: An article from Guido explaining MRO in Python: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html

Comment: I am exactly as confused as OP why `super().gg()` within `B` goes to `C` instead of `A`. It makes sense based on the shown MRO but it also does not make much sense logically just looking at the code and what `B` itself looks like. There is no connection between `B` and `C`.

Comment: @johrshape so do you understand why 'Class C' print comes before 'Class B' print, knowing that class B its inherit before class c?

Comment: Yes - because we're now on the way back _out_ of the call stack, so the order is exactly reversed from the `First` prints on the way in. And @luk2302 that's how multiple inheritance works, remember we're dealing with a `D` that inerits from both `B` and `C`, so that's the connection.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so whenever a super() call happens within B it will check the MRO of the current instance, basically check where in that list the current class is and go to the next one from there? It makes sense that things work that way I was just previously entirely unaware of it.